# How can we distinguish excellent, fascinating and very difficult questions?

Tags: discussion, questions, question-quality

Some questions are "good", well phrased, clear, on topic, well structured, have complete context, useful if you have the exact same problem, but they are specific and not very interesting if you don't have *exactly* that problem.

On the other hand, some questions are really enlightening: very likely to clear things up for even relatively knowledgeable programmers, and for those who already have a good idea of the subject matter, it can help to make things clearer; it should be recommended reading for anyone interested in a topic (not just people trying to solve a specific problem).

How can we help distinguish these generally relevant questions and answers?

Highly voted questions are good, but a high vote count can be the result of being old and often linked, and is a self sustaining process like celebrity: the most known persons are not often the ones most interesting.

INTENT

I want to make it easy to search specifically for such questions that are considered especially { interesting, difficult, tricky } by many people.

Comment: But I think *trending* is a good measurement for that ... The Stackoverflow newsletter always contains a few worth visiting.

Comment: @JonasWilms Trends are self sustaining like celebrity. Can we have a way for users to label questions are "generally interesting and should be famous" as opposed to just specifically "good"?

Comment: Well, what's interesting for you? What's interesting for me? I do have my *favorites* and you have yours ...

Comment: @JonasWilms I'm interested in highly technical questions on topics where we know that many people have vague, contradicting or even plain wrong ideas, even those who write docs for IBM, like threads.

Comment: If there are lots of upvotes and downvotes that could be an indicator of highly controversial topics. Tags with lots of closed questions as too broad could be an indicator of vague topics. Highly technical questions are probably longer than purely pragmatic questions. Finally, if the phrases "language specification", "undefined behavior" occur, it's probably for you.

Comment: Why do we care about the difference? Both types of questions are good, for their own reasons, and they're *all* valuable additions to our knowledge base.

Comment: @CodyGray The difference is that generally interesting questions should be recommended to everyone. Also, marking difficult questions would allow people to browse only those questions.

Comment: Maybe we could introduce some form of favourite-of-the-month contest into which posts (both questions *and* answers) can be submitted manually in some way. It could be an additional sort of "flag" on the post itself saying *"Dis really cool"*, and the posts with the most votes will be highlighted at the end of the month or so. It could come with a special badge too.

Comment: very difficult questions are ones that are poorly specified.

Comment: @KevinB Possibly for that reason, in my opinion SO is broken for difficult questions. I've noticed a tendency to drive-by downvote questions that have taken quite a while to craft without any understanding why the question is problematic (beyond it being difficult to specify). Coupled with minimal reputation for answering hard (and typically limited scope) questions, difficult questions are often just a place for tumbleweed to drift by, with the occasional reputation potshot.

Comment: Put another way, difficult questions are ones that haven’t been properly broken down into smaller problems. The askers ability to do so certainly plays into whether or not the can successfully do it.

Answer (score 3):

Nothing automated is going to give you this information.

The problem with all of those points is that it's *ridiculously* subjective.  The simple metric of "votes" doesn't even come close to defining anything fascinating, difficult, or "excellent".

A human has to intervene and identify these things, and even then it's highly subjective.   What you think is good, interesting, fascinating, etc., may not be to another person.

We need another way to identify these but we can't really *trust* ourselves because, well, if we like a question, we would just upvote it with no indication of anything other than the fact that we liked it.

Comment: My point was that users should be allowed to flag questions are either "difficult", "tricky and more subtle than it looks", "interesting read for everybody in the field"...

Comment: This answer is good, interesting, fascinating, and ridiculous. Where do I click to indicate all of that, again?

Comment: [#StackOverflowKnows](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/12/06/this-week-stackoverflowknows-about-infinity-internet-speak-and-password-storage/) could be viewed as an attempt (quickly located by using [my list](http://pmortensen.eu/world2/?p=89) (though it needs a lot more annotation)).